# How can a remote server (json file) trust an android app

Tags: java, android, jsonp

I have developed Restful Web-Service which returns jsonp objects. I am using this Web-Service in a Java (and sometimes in javascript for hybrid app) android app. Problem is anyone can access this Web-Service I have implemented. (So anyone can create an app and use my data). I want to make it secure by some kind of authentication. Please help me with some solution to secure Web-Service. maybe you suggest me I must use an user name and password like this:

```
http://www.example.com/jsonp.jsonp?username="test"&password="test"
```

you know any one can extract apk file and see it.

or maybe you suggest me check package name of app in remote server before allow.

but anyone can create same pakage-name and use that data...

In brief, How can a remote server trust an android app?

---

**EDIT:** language of server:php

Comment: No, definitely don't put username and password in your app. You should distribute them separately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817643/how-to-secure-restful-web-services