# Different ways to secure RESTful Web service in java used by one or two clients only?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restful-authentication

I have created REST web service in java but need to secure it so that only the authorised clients should be able to access the service. I have never implemented security before. Hence I have no idea where to start to be honest. Do I need to implement any token based security where client need to provide the token in the header of request and I need to verify on my end ?

Answer (score 0):

As RESTful Web Services work with HTTP URL Paths, it is very important to safeguard a RESTful Web Service in the same manner as a website is secured.

**For understanding of importance of security consider the following links:**

http://howtodoinjava.com/security/restful-web-services-security-guide/

[How to secure RESTful web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817643/how-to-secure-restful-web-services)

**While for Implementation using Spring use the given link:**

https://dzone.com/articles/securing-restful-web-service